# Java import package error

Tags: java, package

Hi I am playing around with creating java packages.

I created a package in a folder called admin with a file called Employee - this compiles correctly. Outside this package I have another java file that is importing this. Here is the source code.

```
import java.util.*;
// this works --> import admin.Employee;
import admin.*; // this doesn't

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee h = new Employee("James", 20000);
        System.out.println(h.getName());
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that the second import statement works fine but with the third one I get

- cannot access `Employee`
- bad class file: `./Employee.class`

I am just using javac Hello.java to compile

the employee class is in package admin. The structure is

folder "admin" -> containing "Employee.class" and "Employee.java"
outside this folder is the hello.java file.

```
package admin;
import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{   
private static int nextId;

private int id;
private String name = "";
private double salary;

// static initialization block

static
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    // set nextId to a random number between 0 and 9999
    nextId = generator.nextInt(10000);
}

// object initialization block
{
    id = nextId;
    nextId++;
}

// three overloaded constructors
public Employee(String n, double s)
{
    name = n;
    salary = s;
}

public Employee(double s)
{
    // calls the Employee(String, double) constructor
    this("Employee #" + nextId, s);
}

// Default constructor
public Employee()
{
    // name initialized to ""--see below
    // salary not explicityl set--initialized to 0
    // id initialized in initialization block
}


public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}

public int getId()
{
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you make the class Employee public?

Comment: what is the access specifier for `Employee` class?

Comment: Can you show us the source code of `Employee` , your package structure and how are you compiling the files ?

Comment: Thanks guys, I edited it now with the Employee source code included

Comment: Case sensitive file paths; maybe employee.java i.o. Employee.java?

Comment: i tried this code, it's working for me dude.... :)
just add the package declaration in Employee class..

Comment: I know where I went wrong. Such a schoolboy error, shall I tell you? I had a duplicate Employee file in the same directory as hello.java. I didn't see it because my desktop is littered with icons!

Answer (score 1):

```
package admin;  

import java.util.*;

public class Employee
{
```

also `Employee.java` should be in directory `admin`. e.g

```
./Hello.java  
./admin/Employee.java
```

Comment: I did both of these things. When I copy and pasted the code to stack overflow the "package admin;" was omitted

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the code (without adding package declarations, which is what I think the question was really asking), the basic fix would be to either:

- Compile both classes together (javac Hello.java admin/Employee.java)
- Include the admin folder in your classpath while compiling (-cp path to where admin folder with .class file resides, assuming that's already been compiled)

When you tell it import admin.Employee, and it's in the same source folder, the compiler can infer you want that implicitly compiled. When you import admin.*, you need to include the .java file on the command-line, or include classpath to the .class file, for it to compile.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't fully understand. They both compile fine separately. I put Employee class into a package and then imported it in another file just to see if it would work that way. I think it would be better if I just find another tutorial. My book does not explain this section very well.